# Redireccionar en php y mostrar mensaje sin mostrar la URL de Header

Tags: php, url, session

actualmente despues de realizar un Insert Masivo, redirecciono a mi index, (Desde mi Controller) de la siguente manera:

```
header("location:index.php?li=1");
```

Por lo tanto, en mi index, simplemente hago esto:

```
if(isset($_GET['li']) && $_GET['li'] == 1){ 
 echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
 alertify.alert('Mensaje Informativo', \"Los Límites han sido  cargados correctamente\");
 </script>"; 
 }
```

El problema, es que cuando, recargo la página se muestra el mensaje varias veces, porque está en la URL. Como lo haría en session.?

Cabe destacar, que en mi controller(Donde esta el header) ya tengo una variable de session

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION){

header("location:../../../index.php");
}
```

Saludos, a todos y atentos a sus comentarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo quieres hacer por sesión, cambia el código `header("location:index.php?li=1");` por:

```
$_session["li"]=1;
header("location:index.php");
```

Y en el index cambia `$_GET['li']` por `$_session["li"]`.

Asegurate de que la session este empezada cuando le asignas el 1 en el controller. Y para evitar que el mensaje se repita varias veces, dentro del if cierra la sesión o simplemente cambiale el valor; `$_session["li"]="";` por ejemplo.

Un saludo!

Comment: Dentro de cual if, y amigo? o destruyo la session?

Comment: En este if `if(isset($_GET['li']) && $_GET['li'] == 1){ 
 echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
 alertify.alert('Mensaje Informativo', \"Los Límites han sido  cargados correctamente\");
 </script>"; 
 }` camia los GET por session, y una vez dentro (y que ya no te hace falta el valor de li), cambiale el valor con `$_session["li"]="";`